# firebug is not displaying Complete js file to debug,to place breka points

Tags: javascript, gwt, firebug

HI all,

Firebug is not displaying Complete js file to debug. I m unable to place break points at particular line in js file, half of the file content is display, half of file content is not displaying. please help me what to do to place break points at particular line which can visible line.that js file is gwt compiler generated file.

I am using Firebug 1.5.0 version. Firefox 3.5.

Comment: When you say "not displaying" what do you mean? Can you give an example or better a screenshot?

Comment: Actual js file has 134811 lines, but when i selected js file from script tab, i can able to view 35000 lines only. In that case I cant able to place breakpoint t at 102552 line

Comment: Why are you debugging the compiled JS code? If you are using GWT, you should be debugging the Java code, using, for example, the "normal" debugging tools in Eclipse.

Comment: One problem here that,I have written code for comet(server side pushing) , which completed written in js, due to one problem comet wont work in hostedmode. so i cant debug java code

Comment: You can still put breakpoints "on the source line containing the opening brace of a JSNI method, allowing you to see invocation arguments" (quote from the docs) - that *might* help you in some cases ;) And I'm guessing you are already using `-style PRETTY|DETAILED`? (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#Why_is_my_GWT-generated_JavaScript_gibberish%3F, you can set this using the Eclipse plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug on this fixed recently in Firebug, so try upgrading to the latest version.

Edit: you might need to install the alpha builds: see http://blog.getfirebug.com/2010/03/17/firebug-1-6a8/

Comment: Hi , 

 I installed new one,but still same problem.can suggest me a bit what can be the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, that's all I know, I saw that blog post recently and assumed it was the same as your problem. Maybe just try splitting your js into smaller chunks then.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to change the raw file, you can add the `debugger;` statement at that line, which triggers a breakpoint when it is executed.  Then you won't need to scroll through.

Alternatively, I believe that the Chrome developer tools will allow you to set a breakpoint with a command, rather than clicking, so you won't need to scroll the file either.  Not sure if Chrome is an option.

Comment: Vote up for debugger keyword. I didn't know about that.